# Best practice when reinitialize an Executor

Tags: java, executorservice, executor, executors, threadpoolexecutor

I have a `Swing` application, which uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to perform multiple tasks. At one point, I want to reinitialize everything. I am using `executor.purge();` and       `executor.getQueue().clear()`; Is this enough? Are there any better ways / practices to perform this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Reinitialize all executor internals.. (all runnable counts e.g. submitted runnables, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO you should just [`shutdownNow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow%28%29) the pool and create a new one. If not done too often, it's much simpler. It will also behave safely with already running jobs.
Moreover the semantics of [`purge()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#purge%28%29) are a bit fuzzy.